# What is "seed" for in splitting test-val data in Python and how to come up with a correct number?

Tags: python, random-seed

I'm trying to split my image dataset so it can have a training set and validation set. I found this Python's library called [split-folders](https://pypi.org/project/split-folders/). The syntax is easy to understand

`splitfolders.ratio("input_folder", output="output", seed=1337, ratio=(.8, .1, .1), group_prefix=None)`

But I don't know about this seed parameter and what it does. The description on the page only says that "a seed makes splits reproducible" and that "it shuffles the items" but it doesn't really explain anything for me. I have googled about it and none of them gave me a clear answer. Anyone can give me a brief explanation?

The default number is 1337, but why? What does it mean to have the seed set to 1337? How did they come up with that number? How do I find the correct seed for my dataset?

Comment: Seeds can be any integers (sometimes also floats or byte-like objects) that ensure that if you randomly sample data you can get exactly the same sample each time for repeatability. 1337 has no meaning apart from being a meme, see (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet)

Comment: @pavel Is there any difference if I set the seed to 1, 1337, 50, or any other integer?

Comment: No. The only purpose that if you have some data and you apply some randomness then next time if you have the same data and the same seed, you should get exactly the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you split your corpus to train, validate, and test set, you randomly assign one data point to one of these three sets. Randomness is traceable using **seeds**.

Imagine, you have a random generator, a BlackBox, that gives you a series of random numbers; But for each given seed, the sequence it generates will be always identical. For example, for seed=1337, a random generator will always generate a sequence of random numbers like 12,901,110,1,.... on the same computer.

Why we care about tracing the randomness, especially in the case of dividing the corpus for training? Because most of the time, you want to repeat the same experiment, with the same data. So if you do not use the seed value, each time you run the same experiment, you will end up with different settings for training.

The seed value itself is not important, as long as you get it by some value you know it is fixed during your experiments. I personally set it to a prime number.

Comment: So, I can pick any integer and it won't really matter? If I add one data image into the dataset, will the sequence be different (for the same seed value)? What's the usual seed value people always pick?

Comment: Imagine if you have 1000 images, you need a random generator to uniformly generate 1000 random numbers, and you choose the first 900 for your training, the next 50 for validation, and the next 50 for the test. You want this randomness to not being dependent on how the images are stored in the first place. To generate such 1000 random numbers, you do need to set seed, to be able to regenerate exactly the same sampling if needed. The value of the seed can be any positive number. If you do not set seed, each time you get different randomization--> different data sets sampled.